# Search multiple words in a text using regular expressions (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string, search

I have a method to search a word in a text, both inserted by arguments.

```
public Integer findTheWord(String stringToCheck, String regexString) throws IOException {

        int count = 0;
        Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("\\b" + regexString + "\\b");
        Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher(stringToCheck);

        while (matcher.find()) {
                count++;
                String matchString = matcher.group();
                System.out.println(matchString);
            }
        System.out.println(count);
        return count;
  }
```

How can I insert multiple words and return the occurences of each of them?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - **Logical operators** : `X|Y Either X or Y`. In your case - `[word1|word2|word3]`...

Comment: @dbl That won't help because alternation will return once the left most alternative matches, while OP wants to "return the occurences of each of them".

Comment: Point is taken. I will leave the comment so nobody else do the same misthought...

Comment: My point is passing, by argument, an ArrayList<String> and to verify the matching of each of them.

Comment: I think that if you want an answer you should provide some test cases and expected outputs. Try to put enough of those though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first and easiest option would be to use your actual `findTheWord()` method and create a new method which uses it:

```
public Map<String, Integer> findTheWords(String stringToCheck, List<String> words) {
    return words.stream().distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), word -> findTheWord(stringToCheck, word)));
}

public Integer findTheWord(String stringToCheck, String regexString) {
    Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("\\b" + regexString + "\\b");
    Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher(stringToCheck);

    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The problem with this is if you are using a large number of words to find and a large text, because it iterates over the given string for each word. So another approach would be to create a regex for all words and increment the next found word in your resulting map:

```
public Map<String, Integer> findTheWords(String stringToCheck, List<String> words) {
    Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile(words.stream().distinct().map(word -> "\\b" + word + "\\b").collect(Collectors.joining("|")));
    // creates a pattern like this: "\ba\b|\bb\b|\bc\b|\bd\b|\be\b"
    Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher(stringToCheck);
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String word = matcher.group();
        result.put(word, result.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Beside that you might be considering using a `Set` for the words instead of the `List` because the values are unique, so there is no need to call `.distinct()` on the stream.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap as argument with the input string as key and regex as value, loop through all entries, do your method and return a HashMap with the matched word as key and occurences as value.

```
 public HashMap<String, Integer> findTheWordsAndOccurences(HashMap<String, String> stringsAndRegex) throws IOException {

    HashMap<String, Integer> result = null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : stringsAndRegex.entrySet()){

        String stringToCheck = entry.getKey();
        String regexString = entry.getValue();
        String matchString = "";
        int count = 0;
        Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("\\b" + regexString + "\\b");
        Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher(stringToCheck);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            count++;
            matchString = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(matchString);
            result.put(matchString, count);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```